# How are NASA's mars rovers able to operate with such little energy?

Tags: electrical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, power, energy-efficiency, nuclear-technology

The latest Mars rover being, NASA's Perseverance, uses the Multi-mission radioisotope thermoelectric generator, which has a maximum power output at the beginning of it's operational life of 125 watts, which seems ridiculously low, as even a microwave consumes more power. How is a one tonne machine, with several scientific instrumentation and radio devices able to operate on such low energy consumption?

Comment: With a lot of carefully implemented engineering. And by doing this very slow and deliberately. The haste element in our daily lives causes us to want to do things in a short amount of time, hence the requirement for more power.

Comment: I think you'll find that motors to move wheels can be surprisingly power frugal if you're not moving at blazing speeds. Also, a microwave consumes quite a lot of power compared to other things in your house nearly all the power that a single outlet can provide. The only things that consume more power are large appliances like stoves and maybe washers and dryers.

Comment: Could weightless in space contributes to the saving in power?

Comment: A human can ride a bike all day (and travel maybe 200 miles) with a mechanical power output of less than 125 watts. A mIcrowave oven only uses lots of power because you want want to heat water (which has an abnormally high specific heat ) *quickly*.

Comment: @r13 The surface gravity on mars is about 38% that of earth. That is nowhere close to "weightlessness"

Comment: @alephzero That's why a question mark was used as I didn't want to pretend I knew everything. A person as knowledgeable as you shall provide your comment as the answer with well-formulated equations and calculations to prove your claim, also a few links if necessary.

Comment: @r13 "weight" is irrelevant.  Mass is what matters.  To go from zero momentum to a momentum of  $m*v$  friction aside (and there's almost no atmosphere on Mars) is what matters.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Is momentum the only thing needed for motion and work?